# add_filter : Passing an array instead of the callback function?

Tags: plugin-development, filters, buddypress

I was just reading through BuddyPress code because I want to develop a custom plugin on top of it. I encountered something very peculiar that I haven't seen before and cannot seem to find any material on.

The following code is from a protected function under a class named `BP_Legacy`

```
// Filter BuddyPress template hierarchy and look for page templates.

add_filter( 'bp_get_buddypress_template', array( $this, 
'theme_compat_page_templates' ), 10, 1 );
```

As far as I know, the syntax for `add_filter` is something like

```
add_filter ('hook_name', 'callback_function', $priority, $number_of_arguments)
```

How is it that an array has been passed instead of the callback function? How exactly would this line of code run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass as the callback argument anything which is [callable by PHP definition](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), something that might actually change between PHP versions.

In this specific case the `array($o,$m)` type of notation indicates that the filter will call `$o->$m`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but if I may ask, how did you logically conclude that array($o, $m) will result in the filter calling $o->$m . Is this how add_filter works when an array is passed ?

Comment: no, that is how you generally do a callable for a method of an object in PHP